# High Lighting Data in dygraph using a Date as x-axis

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am having trouble highlighting my dygraph using a Date as my a axis.  It works if I just use a number as the x axis but not with dates. This is just a sample of what I am doing.  I tried many things but still no luck any help would be great.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function reveal(toshow) {
    document.getElementById(toshow).style.display='block';
    return false;}
    </script>





<script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>make sure</div>
  <div id="graphdiv" style="width:800px; height:500px;"></div>




  <script type="text/javascript" >

    g = new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
 "myTime,INTERCEPTOR LEVEL \n" +
"01/01/2016,3 \n" +
"01/02/2016,9 \n" +
"01/03/2016,15 \n" +
"01/04/2016,6 \n" +
"01/06/2016,8 \n" +
"01/07/2016,7 \n" +
"01/08/2016,5 \n" +
"01/09/2016,1 \n" +
"01/10/2016,10 \n" ,

   { underlayCallback: 
function(canvas, area, g) {
   var bottom_left = g.toDomCoords("01/04/2016", 0);
              var top_right = g.toDomCoords("01/05/2016", +14);

              var left = bottom_left[0];
              var right = top_right[0];




        canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 102, 1.0)";

              canvas.fillRect(left, area.y, right - left , area.h);




   }


}           

);
     </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, John. Do you have an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: I am just using this as an example to show how the highlights do not work with dates only numbers on the x axis.  In reality I am passing a parameter to a asp.net web page and it connects to a mssql data base.  Then uses a string builder to create the java script to make the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I have to convert the dateTime that is being used for the highlights to the number of milliseconds since 1970.  Then pass that number in the **g.toDomXCoord(milliseconds since 1970)**.  That will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use new Date instead of string format.

```
   var bottom_left = g.toDomCoords(new Date('2007/07/01'), -90);
   var top_right = g.toDomCoords(new Date('2008/01/01'), +90);
```

[see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPbND.png)

Comment: Thanks will try on next project.

Answer (score 0):

Kill double-quotes. That work.

Comment: Is that an answer?